# Gson library when parse string contain special char \u

Tags: gson, special-characters

I have a simple code like that:

```
 JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
 JsonElement element = parser.parse("{\"description\":\"c:\\userDescription.txt\"}");
 JsonObject attributes = element.getAsJsonObject();
 System.out.println(attributes);
```

I expect the outout is:

```
{"description":"c:\userDescription.txt"}
```

but actually I have the exeption:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "serD"
```

Can you help me, what should the input is to get the expect output:

```
 {"description":"c:\userDescription.txt"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Java string is one character long, the `\` character:

```
String s = "\\";
```

Like Java, JSON uses `\` as its escape character. So you need to escape for Java *and* for JSON. Try this:

```
JsonElement element = parser.parse("{\"description\":\"c:\\\\userDescription.txt\"}");
```

Comment: If I do that, the output is : {"description":"c:\\userDescription.txt"}
But my expect is {"description":"c:\userDescription.txt"}

Comment: Your expectation is invalid JSON. The \ character must be escaped.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I solved the problem by your suggestion.